# Both validation loss and accuracy with a spike

Tags: validation, deep-learning, computer-vision, transfer-learning, conv-neural-network

I use Pytorch to do an image classification task with transfer learning ResNet18. I used fine-tuning for the transfer learning network. I have 16 classes with 100 training images and 24 validation images for each. Below are the loss plot and accuracy plot. My questions are:
1. Are the training process correct? I mean whether there is overfitting.
2. Why is there a spike in the 4th epoch? Does it mean overfitting? Thanks
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There is not any significant overfitting as your validation loss/accuracy is close to training loss/accuracy. Still, if you want to reduce the margin further you may use image augmentation techniques or regularization.
2. The spike in that particular epoch doesn't necessarily mean overfitting as your network was able to recover from it later. This probably happened due to the weights being in a bad local minima. You can check if this is common or just an aberration by running the experiment multiple times using different random seed. In the former case, using a different optimizer or lowering the learning rate might help.